# Date comparison in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, date

How do you declare a date datatype in a table? Is it simply the following?

```
CREATE TABLE sampleDB (..., sampledate DATE, ...)
```

Now, if I want to query from that using a string through a POST form:

```
<?php
    $formdate = $_POST["inputname"];

    if($formdate) {
        echo "Searching using query: ".$formdate."<br>";
        $db = new SQLiteDatabase("testDB.db");
        $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM sampleDB WHERE sampledate = ".$formdate);
        while($entry = $query->fetch(SQLITE_ASSOC)) {
            echo "result: " ... "<br>";
        }
    }
?>
```

This doesn't seem to work. It doesn't return the entry that I want.

When I store the date as a string and compare strings, all is well, but if SQLite has a DATE data type, I think there should be way to use it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a vulnerability in the code you posted that seems to make it easy for any user to inject arbitrary SQL commands. Two common ways to fix it are (1) sanitizing the input and (2) using an API that separates commands from (possibly untrusted) arguments. For (1) I'd look for SQL-specific escape functions in the PHP documentation. A well-known example for (2) is Perl's DBI. (I don't know whether there is a comparable library for PHP.)

In SQLite, there is no date or time type. If you already have date strings in the database, you'll have to make sure that they are consistently formatted. [Date and Time Functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) from the SQLite manual lists some functions that might come useful for your queries.

Comment: To whomever voted my answer down. Saying "I don't like your answer" without giving a reason is lame.

Comment: First, your response is rude. This site is for programming questions no matter what the level of expertise.

Second, you told me about a problem without telling me how to fix it. What part is vulnerable to injection attacks? How do I fix that?

Third, thank you for telling me that SQLite doesn't have a date or time type. That's the only part of your response that was immediately useful to me.

Finally, I'm looking for a fast answer; not a programming lesson. 
From my understanding, that's what Stack Overflow is about: quick ANSWERS to our programming questions.

Comment: Your question was stated in a way that made it impossible for me to give you a quick answer, just some pointers. I assumed that you'd be able to do some (Google) research on what an SQL injection attack is, how to spot a vulnerability and fix it. Have fun with my revised answer.